# Can you get the field base name instead of the translated name when using the JIRA rest api?

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

The [JIRA rest api documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue#JIRARESTAPIExample-CreateIssue-Exampleofcreatinganissueusingcustomfields) suggests that you should use the field name when sending in a custom field for a create issue request, because they are not unique across instances.

However, the field names you receive from calling the meta-data on a project are translated based on the language settings of the user. That also means that the field names are subject to change, because translations are controlled by the client.

Is there any way to recover the field's base name (which is not changeable) rather than the field's translated name, when calling the createmeta function?

(Or another best practice for determining which custom field you need to set which data to?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you Can Not.
In my recent plugin I had to add fields to the settings screen to map Epic Name and Epic Link:

```
 - Epic Name custom field name:
 - Epic Link custom field name:
```